# Define unique key constraints that conditionally apply to different documents within the same container/partition

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Given the following documents which are stored in the same container and partition where the `Type` property denotes what the documents type is (`DocumentA` or `DocumentB`):

```
class DocumentA 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParitionKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

class DocumentB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParitionKey { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to create [unique key constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys) that only apply to either `DocumentA` or `DocumentB`?

For example, could I create a unique key constraint on `DocumentA`'s `Name` property and another for `DocumentB`'s `Value` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying unique constraints conditionally based on another property value **is not possible**, AFAIK.

I would consider instead:

#### Is the unique constraint required at DB-level?

Is it really so dangerous that you need to verify this on every data-modifying operation? Maybe it is, and it's not a huge burden, but quite often in the schema-less world there are many constraints not enforced on data layer, but in business layer. Contrary to relational-data mindset, it usually works better in NOSQL to keep the storage dumb (except having good targeted indexes for performance) and saving on create/update RU cost may matter more in the big picture.

Also, changing unique constraints is a PITA, so having one requires you to be really sure that it can accommodate every document type changes and new document types. For example, what if `DocumentC` pops up with both `Name` and `Value`?

#### Why force documents with different requirements into the same container?

If the unique constraints are really-really needed, then you could have the cake and eat it too by just using **[shared-throughput database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#set-throughput-on-a-database) and have N containers instead**, i.e. differentiated by shared partition key, unique constraints and perhaps main indexes on common structure parts. This has the additional benefits of more granular RBAC access control, more precise indexes, cheaper scans, better names, more readable code, clearer dependencies etc.

On the downsides of having too many containers:

- more cumbersome to manage
- there's a limit (25?) how many containers can be put into same
  shared-throughput database.
- loss of ability to query across "types" (for example "docs created between X and Y", etc)

Comment: The entire reason I was asking this question is because we're trying to determine if we should use multiple containers or a single container where we differentiate the document type by the `type` property. Your last paragraph hits the nail on the head for me.

Comment: The sweet spot is to have both tactics in use. Docs similar enough in the same container, and different animals separately. This also simplifies reorg later for both merge and splits. Future has the tendency to bring unexpected requirements. I also added a few multi-container downsides to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, conditional unique constraints aren't a feature, but you could achieve your goal by using a composite unique key on the paths '/Name' and '/Type' and '/Value'

> Sparse unique keys are not supported. If some unique path values are missing, they're treated as null values, which take part in the uniqueness constraint. For this reason, there can be only a single item with a null value to satisfy this constraint.

This will resolve in either /Name of /Value being null. In your case, this is exactly what you want.

Little heads up:
I see you're using a GUID as partition key. Unique keys are limited to their partition.

> The partition key combined with the unique key guarantees the uniqueness of an item within the scope of the container.

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys#define-a-unique-key)

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying and I think you're right that would work,

Comment: So there is an issue here. If I have multiple documents of type `DocumentA` for example, then one of the composite key constraints would resolve to `/Type DocumentA /Value null` which would stop me from being able to add multiple `DocumentA` documents.

Comment: The composite key is artificial and would provide only partial requirement enforcement. One could bypass the constraint by adding a property with random value to either `value` for `documentA`, or `name` to `documentB`. Cannot use for security/critical path, but may be beneficial for failing earlier on some simpler cases.